# Can electromagnetic waves be interpreted as a collection of infinite coupled oscillators?

Tags: electromagnetism, coupled-oscillators

I recently learned, for the first time, that the behavior of waves can be derived by treating them as an infinite set of coupled oscillators. This makes sense for waves whose medium is matter; it's easy to see how water waves, for instance, can be seen as the individual water molecules tugging on their neighbors as they oscillate.

At the same time, however, I've only ever seen electromagnetic waves treated continuously, and again this makes the most sense, since electromagnetic waves are just oscillations in a continuous field. But I wonder, is there an interpretation of EM waves as a set of discrete coupled oscillators? Would such a treatment be useful in any way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.

Consider electromagnetic fields in a square box of volume $V = L^3$.  One can then impose periodic boundary conditions on the vector potential, and one arrives at the following expansion in terms of Fourier modes:
\begin{align}
  \mathbf A(t,\mathbf x) = \sum_\mathbf k\sum_r \left(\frac{\hbar c^2}{2V\omega_\mathbf k}\right)^{1/2} \mathbf \epsilon_r(\mathbf k)(a_r(\mathbf k)e^{i(\mathbf k\cdot \mathbf x-\omega_\mathbf k t)} + a_r^\dagger(\mathbf k)e^{-i(\mathbf k\cdot \mathbf x-\omega_\mathbf k t)})
\end{align}
where $\omega_\mathbf k = c|\mathbf k|$ and the $\mathbf \epsilon$'s are polarization vectors.  Because we are quantizing in a box with periodic boundary conditions, the sum over $\mathbf k$ is over the countable (discrete) set of wavevectors given by
\begin{align}
  \mathbf k = \frac{2\pi}{L}(n_1, n_2, n_3), \qquad n_i = 0,\pm 1, \pm 2, \dots
\end{align}
We then impose the creation-annihiliation commutation relations on the Fourier modes $a_r^\dagger(\mathbf k)$ and $a_r(\mathbf k)$, so we can treat the field as being composed of the excitations of a discrete number of oscillators.

Comment: Thank you, this looks like a very good answer! I'm going to quickly refresh my knowledge of wavevectors (and perhaps Fourier series) to make sure I don't have any questions before I accept it, but this seems to be exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @EtaZetaTheta Sure thing.  As another note, I'd recommend checking out Mandl and Shaw's quantum field theory text; the first few sections of the text cover precisely this, namely quantizing the electromagnetic field in a box by treating it as a countably infinite number of oscillators.  It's a very nice, not-too-difficult treatment.

Comment: Perfect, thank you, and I'll be sure to look into that text. I'm about to start my second course on QM, including QFT, so this will be perfect.

Comment: Even nicer, in my opinion, is the recent book by Mukhanov: Introduction to quantum effects in gravity. Don't be scared because of the title: *the book builds up from reasonable undergrad level* and has an *incredibly* detailed discussion of harmonic oscillators, including a section on quantizing a perturbed oscillator (very enlightening). Of course, the actual QFT in curved spacetime that follows is also fascinating ;)

Comment: In particular, I find it needs to be emphasized (and Mukhanov does exactly this) more that the field is **not** a collection of harmonic oscillators in real space! It is only in Fourier space, so this relation between the two is not something one can visualize so easily, and mostly a mathematical tool.

Comment: @Danu Thanks for the reference; I've never heard of that text, and it seems great!

Comment: @joshphysics Yes, it's quite amazing. I'm reading it as part of my preparation for my (bachelor's) thesis on scalar field theories in de Sitter, and it's given me insights and intuition in all kinds of corners of physics. It is also available legally online (it's technically a draft, but I got a chance to compare side-by-side with the real text and it's essentially identical).